# Why when light enters to another medium it changes its direction?

Tags: optics, speed-of-light, refraction

When people explain why light changes direction when it goes into other medium with different refraction index, they usually say because light changes its speed when it goes to a different medium. But why does light changes direction when it changes speed? It could change its speed while maintaining the same direction!

Why is that responce is so common while (at least for me) I think it doesn't answer the question at all!

What I'm missing?   How is that answer answers my question?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, light could have a different speed in the same direction; that’s what happens at normal incidence (where there’s no refraction). The thing that’s actually conserved is the *in-plane component of momentum*, $k_x$. At normal incidence, $k_x=0$ regardless of the refractive index, so there’s no need to refract. But at oblique incidence, without refraction in the medium, $k_x$ would increase because $k\propto n$. So, light bends toward normal incidence a bit to correspondingly reduce $k_x$ and conserve it across the boundary.